# Does setting `constraint.isActive = false` deallocate the constraint?

Tags: swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

Say I want to remove a constraint, traditionally I would do:

```
view.removeConstraint(constraint)
```

However, there is now the new isActive methods for installing/uninstalling constraints.

If I do the following:

```
constraint.isActive = false
```

Will it remove it from memory correctly?

Comment: Why the concern? Sure, the constraint is no longer *active*. But it sounds like your concern is memory? Why?

Comment: If it doesn't actually release it from memory, and I continuously install/remove constraints, it'll eat up more and more of the device's memory. We generally want objects to be deallocated when they are no longer in use.

Comment: I think you have it wrong. Constraints are a part of a view. You release a view, you release the constraints. (BTW, why not just use ARC?) You don't *install/remove* constraints, you *activate/deactivate* them. I get it's an adjustment to coding strategies, but again, we're no longer working in the stone age where mainframes have a core memory of 64K, we're talking iOS/macOS devices (more and more using Swift and ARC instead of Obj-C and manual memory allocation and release) on devices using hundreds of GB.

Comment: In case my *key* point was missed - constraints do not take up memory, views do. Let the OS do your work! (Also, learn to *create* the constraints, then *activate* or *deactivate* properly.

Answer (score 9):

Yes,

```
constraint.isActive = false
```

is doing the same thing as:

```
viewThatOwnsConstraint.removeConstraint(constraint)
```

So if the only thing holding on to the constraint was the view, then this will correctly remove it from memory.

---

Here's the proof:

```
let view = UIView()

weak var weakView: UIView? = nil
autoreleasepool {
  weakView = UIView()
}
assert(weakView == nil)

// Traditional way of removing constraints ensures that the constraint is deallocated

weak var weakConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? = nil
autoreleasepool {
  weakConstraint = view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
}
assert(weakConstraint == nil) // nothing is holding on to the constraint

autoreleasepool {
  weakConstraint = view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
  view.addConstraint(weakConstraint!)
}
assert(weakConstraint != nil)

autoreleasepool {
  view.removeConstraint(weakConstraint!)
}
assert(weakConstraint == nil)

// New way of removing constraints:

assert(weakConstraint == nil)

autoreleasepool {
  weakConstraint = view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
  weakConstraint!.isActive = true
}
assert(weakConstraint != nil)

autoreleasepool {
  weakConstraint!.isActive = false
}
assert(weakConstraint == nil)
```

Comment: that does not mean that *all* references are removed as stated in your question. that only means the view does not retain the constraint anymore, other references are not affected with this action

Comment: @MertBuran good point. I updated the question title to reflect what I was actually wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Let say if you define the constraint outlet as `weak var` in unreusable `UIViewController`, and you deactivate it by `constraint.isActive = false` will remove it from the memory.

However, if you define the constraint outlet as `weak var` in reusable view like `UICollectionViewCell`, and this `UICollectionViewCell` is rendered as multiple views in a parent view. Deactivating it by `constraint.isActive = false` won't remove it from the memory since the other cells still hold the reference for that constraint.

Defining the constraint outlet as (strong) `var`, executing `constraint.isActive = false` won't remove it from the memory despite UIView it's defined on.